# Spring Data - is Slice faster than Page if it is using order by?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data

If using `org.springframework.data.domain.Slice` instead of `org.springframework.data.domain.Page` for returning pageable results is faster in general - because Slice does not call count(*) - is it still faster if query is also doing an order by ?

Other way to put it, is the first example **slower** than the second ?

First example using `Page`:

```
Pageable sortedByName = PageRequest.of(0, 3, Sort.by("name"));
Page<Employee> firstEmployeePage = employeeRepository.findAll(sortedByName);
```

Second example using `Slice`:

```
Pageable sortedByName = PageRequest.of(0, 3, Sort.by("name"));
Slice<Employee> firstEmployeePage = employeeRepository.findAll(sortedByName);
```

Answer (score 0):

A `Page` execution is almost the same as querying for a `Slice` and doing a count query. The only difference is that `Slice` will use `LIMIT (n+1)`. With that knowledge you should understand that a slice execution is always faster as a count query will usually have to "visit all rows" through some means to determine the count.

Comment: What I actually wanted to find out is if Page and Slice have the same performance when an "order by" is used. From my understanding, when "order by" is executed, the engine should iterate through all rows before returning a page/slice, so even though Slice isn't executing count(*), it already went through all the rows (because it must know the order) and therefore I expect that both (Slice and Page) to have the same performance.

Comment: The count query still needs to look at some data structures, possibly do joins, and for big tables do IO, so the count query is what will make everything slower. A slice or a page do not make sense without ordering, so you always need a `order by`.